# Remove "Select * from dual" from UNION in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, union, jooq

Here's the code:

```
SelectQuery<Record> resultQuery = dslContext.selectQuery();
for(int floor : floors) {
    method1(resultQuery,floor);
}
```

And then:

```
method1(SelectQuery<Record> resultQuery,int floor){
    SelectQuery<Record> query = dslContext.selectQuery();
    /*
     Now I am creating subqueries for parameter floor by adding condition 
     in above created query 
    */

    resultQuery.union(query);
}
```

Issue is that in final query(resultQuery)  I am getting "Select * from dual" appended. It is adding because I created "resultQuery" as empty.

Is there any way I can replace or remove "Select * from dual" from final query.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Imperative style:

```java
SelectQuery<Record> result = null;
for (int floor : floors) {
    result = method1(result, floor);
}
```

With:

```java
SelectQuery<Record> method1(SelectQuery<Record> result, int floor) {
    SelectQuery<Record> query = dslContext.selectQuery();

    /* your logic ... */

    if (result == null)
        return query;
    else
        return result.union(query);
}
```

#### Functional style

```java
Optional<Select<Record>> result =
floors.stream()
      .map(this::method2)
      .reduce(Select::union)
```

With:

```java
Select<Record> method2(int floor) {
    SelectQuery<Record> query = dslContext.selectQuery();

    /* your logic ... */

    return query;
}
```

See also:

- [Union query with multiple selects post java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48991918/521799)
- https://blog.jooq.org/2018/02/27/map-reducing-a-set-of-values-into-a-dynamic-sql-union-query/